# Method for each String

Tags: java, sql, telegram-bot

Doing sql request, to get some info from my db

```
public String chat_id() {
    String userid = null;
    try {

        PreparedStatement st = null;
        String query = "select chat_id FROM id";
        st = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            userid = rs.getString("chat_id");
            System.out.println("userid : " + userid);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userid;

}
```

Other class, other method, reurnt info from db to String, but, in my data base not one value for my requst,

```
public void sendMsg(){

    Login lgc= new Login();
    
  String chat = lgc.chat_id();
  String text = "test";
  
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();         
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);                           
    sendMessage.setChatId(chat);    
  //sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());   
    sendMessage.setText(text);                                 
    try {
       execute(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There is a question.: Method sendMsg need to be run for several values of String chat_id. At this moment it`s run for last value from db. what shell I do?

Comment: Why would you need to send several messages to the same `chatId`?  It seems you need to have a chat with a list of users (and users may have multiple chats) who have list of messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them into a list, then read them appropriately in the other class like so:

```
 public List<String> chat_id() {
     String userid = null;
     List<String> userids = new ArrayList<>();
     try {
        
         PreparedStatement st = null;
         String query = "select chat_id FROM id";
         st = con.prepareStatement(query);
         rs = st.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {
             userid = rs.getString("chat_id");
             userids.add(userid);
             System.out.println("userid : " + userid);
         }
     } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return userids;

 }
```

You can get the values from the list like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < userids.size; i++){
    String userid = userids.get(i);
}
```